Extracting images out of multiple different RSS feeds
Working on a project that pulls articles from 20+ rss feeds and a variety of feed formats for where an articles image is.
I'm happy for the article image to be missing in some cases, and I'll fall back to a set image, but I don't want that happening more than 20% of the time.
Using Python & Feedparser (in a DJANGO Project) I've gotten this far:
# Try and get the image url
try: 
    # Looking for images embedded in enclosures
    post_image = sanitize_url(str(c.enclosures[0].href))
except:
    try:
        # Looking for images embedded in media content
        post_image = sanitize_url(str(c.media_content[0]["url"]))
    except:
        try:
            # Looking for images embedded in content
            post_image = sanitize_url(c.content[0]["value"])
        except:
            post_image = "no image found"

I had to build a sanitize URL function that does 3 things:

Takes a string that extracts out a URL (in situations where the above pulls more than the URL)
Trim URLS down to remove parameters that might cause problems (i.e 342.jpg?w=25)
A final check of the string to make sure it has a mimetype in case the final url is not an image.

I'm going in circles here, for every example, there are some RSS feeds this works, while others don't work. The variety of RSS structures is driving me a bit batty.
Any advice on what I should do here? I can't keep adding more and more functions and loops to it.

So you are trying to build a generalized image extractor, it seems that there are multiple different formats that each feed uses, why not separate the RSS feeds into their own unique formatting to return the correct version for each feed (since they are unique) [selecting which instruction set to use based on the feed it comes from]. If however, you are trying to go along this generalized path could you give some more examples of what some of the differences are between the Feeds, as you may be overgeneralizing a cases and may need a more targeted check.

Yes, I'm pulling from 20+ feeds and there seems to be huge variety of where the article image is stored.

https://reconnectrecap.substack.com/feed
https://aftermath.site/rss
https://legendsoflocalization.com/feed/
https://wavelengths.online/posts_feed
https://www.pentadact.com/rss
These are my examples. All substacks seem to operate the same, with aftermath and legends being also different. Pentadact is the worst offender despite being a Wordpress site. its variety and quality is poor.
